# Is it worth it to use a thread for network requests in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing an app that makes lots of requests over the LAN and some cloud providers, periodically, while on screen. I am worried about user experience and don't want the screen to lag between updates.

The app uses redux to keep state, and I am already using heavily the `InteractionManager` and debounce/throttle calls to avoid the requests to hang the Javascript thread. I guess it just would be way easier if, by norm, I moved all those requests to a separate thread / worker. I am making any wrong assumptions? Is it worth it to use a thread for network requests in React Native?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Network requests

You can make requests from JavaScript as usual, using e.g. the [fetch API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html).

Your network request won't block the UI. React Native will execute the network request using a background native (Java / Obj-C) thread. There is only one JavaScript thread where all your JS code runs, React Native doesn't have support for web workers.

If you want to learn about the architecture of React Native you can watch [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8N4f4h6SThc&t=8m40s).

## Updating the UI

Probably the easiest thing to do here would be to send fewer requests, less frequently. If you for absolutely have to send many requests, try to at least throttle the UI updates as you said.

If that doesn't help you could also look at the [React performance tips](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html), some of which (e.g. `PureComponent`) apply to React Native.

Comment: That is interesting, you said that react native run all requests in different threads internally? But after that you also said that there is one only javascript thread, so I am a little bit confused there. I know React Native does not support web workers out of the hood but you can add packages and native code to solve it.

Comment: There is one JavaScript thread (where all your JavaScript code runs) and multiple native (Java, Obj-C) threads which you normally don't have to worry about when writing JS code. You could watch this talk or read up on RN architecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8N4f4h6SThc&t=8m40s